# Update of /etc/resolve.conf needs restart of application

Tags: linux, networking, dns, systemd-resolved

I am working with an embedded linux Target (ARM) and have the following problem:
When /etc/resolv.conf is updated, while a process is running (e.g. C Program using gethostbyname()) the running process does not take care about the new nameserver entry until it is restarted.

The DNS entry has been made with systemd-resolve -i eth0 --set-dns="ipaddr"

If I try the same with my desktop linux any change to /etc/resolv.conf is used immediately by a running processes without restart.

How can I see whats happening (or not happening) in the background when /etc/resolv.conf is beeing modified? What service could be missing on the embedded target?
Why does it work after restart of the application?

Comment: maybe [nscd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/nscd)

Comment: is it resolvE.conf or resolv.conf?

Comment: Thanks, of course resolv.conf. But typo is only at the posting. Happens to me all the time. Why don't they name the file correctly ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `resolve` to your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` before `dns` entry, so hosts line will look like:

```
hosts:          files mymachines resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname
```

Comment: Thanks this solves the problem like magic ;-)

Comment: Do you know where I can find more information regarding nsswitch.conf? At the man page there is no explanation about  the "resolve" keyword.

Comment: That part of nss subsystem is just plugable modules, and systemd provides it's own module to be plugged to nss. Here are docs for module: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/nss-resolve.html